# Express js routing and mysql query not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm just now started to learn Node and Express, I have some probelm with the routes in express. I want a well modular code for routing. I want to query some data from mysql database:

Here is my app.js(it is on "public_html" directory):

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var app = express();

var staticPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './');
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

routes.init(app);
module.exports = app;

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Server is listening on port: 3000');
});
```

Next file: "public_html/routes/index.js":

```
exports.init = function(app){

//electronics routes
app.use('/laptop', require('./laptop'));
};
```

"public_html/routes/laptop/index.js":

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/laptop', require('./modules/laptop'));
module.exports = router;
```

"public_html/routes/laptop/modules/laptop.js":

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
 {
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'admin',
   password : 'xxxxxxx',
   database : 'database',
 }

);

module.exports = function(req, res){

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM laptop';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;

res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
});

connection.end();
};
```

I want to keep this modularity even if its look like a bit over complicated, in the future I will need it.
So the problem is it's just doesn't working, I think its just a stupid error somewhere, but I don't find it and on the internet there is only simple route examples so I cant use them in this case.

Comment: This is unrelated, but why are you making your server code public for all to see (you're setting `express.static()` to the directory containing your code)? `public_html` is generally reserved for client-side html/js/css/similar assets only.

Comment: Also you're trying to end the response twice in your `laptop.js`.

Comment: Yeah I know about it, I saw in a many examples what your talking about. I'll also fix it, but anyway thanks the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely in your routing.

You're mounting a separate router at `/laptop`. Within that mounted router you're setting up a `/laptop` (GET) route on top of that, so the full path would be `/laptop/laptop`.

Comment: Noit really understand you mean this?:

Comment: app.use('/laptop', require('./laptop/laptop'));

Comment: Yes you were right, I changed this line: router.get('/', require('./modules/laptop')); and now its working thanks a lot.